# Excel/VBA Show or hide rows based on specific cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to find a way to show or hide rows 55:57 based on the value in Cell J52.  Ideally, I would want this to happen in Real-Time Using VBA.

[image]

The value in J52 goes from 0 - 3.

I tried this code but it doesn't work as it throws an error stating "Sub or Function not defined":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
StartRow = 55
EndRow = 57
Tar = C52
For i = Tar To Tar
If Cell(i).Value = "Individuals" Then
Cells(StartRow, EndRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Cells(StartRow, EndRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You're getting that message as you're using `Cell(i).Value` instead of `Cells(i).Value`.  You're code won't work though as `Tar = C52` will create Tar as a variant and C52 as a variant - I guess it's a cell range, but to VBA C52 is just an undefined variable (which `Option Explicit` would highlight).  So Tar and C52 will equal 0.

Comment: Also, `Worksheet_SelectionChange` will fire when you move from one cell to another (you change the selected cell), rather than when you change cell C52 value.

Comment: Your code also appears to look at C52 being "Individuals", but your question says based on J52 which contains the value 0 - 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will only fire when you change the value in C52.  It does what your code suggests, rather than what your question suggests.

`(Target.Value = "Individuals")` will return TRUE/FALSE based on the value of Target - Target being the cell you changed (C52).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$52" Then
        Range("55:57").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "Individuals")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly lazy coding but I think it achieves what you're after?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Range("55:57").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("C52") = "Individuals")
End Sub
```